# How to run a website on tomcat in ubuntu?

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, jboss

Well, I would like to run a website that was made using eclipse and jboss in my tomcat server that is running.

Structure of the app:

app/build/
app/resources/
app/src/
app/WebContent/

Comment: What is a 'webapp jboss'?

Comment: Jboss and tomcat are both JEE application servers. Both are capable of running JEE web applications. Both can be deployed on ubuntu.

Comment: Tomcat isn't a JEE application server. It's a Java Servlet Container. TomEE is the JEE Application Server version of Tomcat.

Comment: Tomcat is a servlet/JSP engine.  Unless you add EJB capability, it is not a 1:1 substutute for JBOSS, which is a full Java EE app server.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's docs are pretty good, have you actually looked for a solution at all?

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/tomcat.html

That'll walk you through the setup and configuration.

Comment: I installed tomcat and saw that the server is running ... but I have an app that has been done in eclipse and tried to play the same folder to run and have not seen results yet do not know where I am going wrong ..

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Install Tomcat.
2. Start Tomcat.
3. Create a WAR file for your app.
4. Deploy the WAR file in the Tomcat /webapps folder.

Comment: I have tomcat running as I would create the file "war" via the command line?

Comment: A WAR is nothing more than a ZIP file with a particular format.  You should know what that is.  Do you?

Comment: I'm looking for how to make war file on my project.